Are there 16mm still film cameras with double exposure capability?
I am knowledgeable about 110 and 16mm and their differences, I use both formats regularly.
I am looking for a 16mm still photography camera (they are much easier to load with various types of movie film than 110), that has manual controls like multiple exposure and Bulb pose (and a decent - not plastic lens).
Was such a camera ever produced?


You probably will not find any that has double exposure built in. But you can find some with mechanical shutter reset/film advance and bulb mode... those are usually easy to manipulate into making a double exposure (mechanically disengage film advance during shutter reset).
Zany 16 and Rubina 16 might be contenders...

Which ones do you think I could easily manipulate into making double exposures?
